# Upgrading from Windows XP to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dual-boot

Okay, even though the title says a different thing, this does mostly only affect my Ubuntu Installation.

I have a dualboot setup for Windows XP and Ubuntu, Windows had been installed first, then Ubuntu, etc.
Now I want to "upgrade" my Windows XP Installation to Windows 7. I don't care whether I lose my Windows XP files or not; but I **REALLY** do *not* want to lose my Ubuntu Installation.

So, How would I get rid of Windows XP, install Windows 7, keep my Ubuntu Installation intact, and if possible, do all that with not too much hazzle?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

simply install windows 7 on the windows xp drive, then boot from Ubuntu Live CD and do tutorial from the link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows